# How to stop the command from taking in input

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am creating a program that uses a keyboard shortcut using [pyhk](http://www.schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/pyhk-end-user-documentation/). In the following code I am not able to stop `tri.start()` from taking input more than once.

```
    import pyhk
    print "Press ALT + 1"
    def shortcut():
        print "keyboard shortcut"

    #create pyhk class instance
    tri = pyhk.pyhk()

    #add hotkey. Assigning the keyboard shortcut.
    tri.addHotkey(['Alt', '1'], shortcut)

    #start looking for hotkey
    tri.start()

    # removing the hotkey. Should remove the assigned shortcut         
    tri.removeHotkey()
```

When I press Alt+1, it prints "keyboard shortcut". Then again when I press Alt+1, it again prints "keyboard shortcut", which it should not because the `tri.removeHotkey()` part should run removing the assigned shortcut.

Its like the program is stuck at `tri.start()` waiting for input. How can we make it take input only once and then run the next part of the code.

Comment: Is there actually a loop here? It looks like it doesn't wait for input, it just defines the hotkey and then removes it immediately.

Comment: He thinks that when you register the hotKey there will be a loop running to check the key press and he is asking how to remove the registed hotKey.

Comment: Are you using this as a script in another program? Like Blender?

Comment: @octern - You are correct. But, the problem is that it is not running that part. I have modified the question, please check again. @ Ganessh Kumar RP - You are correct. @ moter - no

Comment: You need to tell the removeHotkey what hotkey to remove. Docs: http://www.schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/pyhk-end-user-documentation/#hotkey-removal

Comment: @PhilH - Correct. But the `tri.removeHotkey()` should remove all hotkeys in use. Even the `tri.removeHotkey(['Alt', '1'])` is not working.